# Create a 'dynamic list' during iteration in python

Tags: python, integer, modulo

**Background**

Let there be a set of integers

```
trialinteg = [231,355,112,1432,2434,5235,7896,7776,27421,42342]
```

Then it is possible to classify them into different equivalence classes modulo 6

**Problem**

Could we create an algorithm to classify all these integers into their respective equivalence class and store the results in a dictionary in python?

For example

```
d = {"class0": [112,1432,..], "class1": [231,...], ...}
```

More importantly, can we make d changes its size and names of the keys as the integer by which we define equivalence class (in this example, 6) changes?

**Progress**

It is possible to store all integers of equivalence class 0 modulo 6 in a list. But it is not clear how one can create a 'dynamic' dictionary that adjusts its size and names of the key when the integer in question changes (for example from 6 to 121).

```
moduloclasszero=[]
for num in trialinteg:
    while num % 6 != 0:

        print(f"{num} is not of class 0")
        print(f"But {num} is of class {num % 6}")
        print("now proceed to restore it to 0")

        num = num + (6-(num % 6))
    else: 
        print(f"{num} is of class 0")
        moduloclasszero.append(num)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

trialinteg = [231,355,112,1432,2434,5235,7896,7776,27421,42342]

d = defaultdict(list)

for x in trialinteg:
    d[f'class{x % 6}'].append(x)

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'class3': [231, 5235], 'class1': [355, 27421], 'class4': [112, 1432, 2434], 'class0': [7896, 7776, 42342]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the class value itself for your dictionary key.

```
my_mod = 6
for num in trialinteg:
    d[num % my_mod].append(num)
```

I'll assume that you can already handle initializing the dict; if not, look at supporting questions on this site.

A dict comprehension can do this in a single assignment statement:

```
trial = [231,355,112,1432,2434,5235,7896,7776,27421,42342]
d = {equi: [i for i in trial if i%my_mod == equi] 
     for equi in range(my_mod)}
```

Resulting value of d:

```
{0: [7896, 7776, 42342],
 1: [355, 27421],
 2: [],
 3: [231, 5235],
 4: [112, 1432, 2434],
 5: [] }
```